# R for loop on objects in global environment to subset on one variable

Tags: r, object, for-loop

Say I have 3 objects (A, B and C) in my global environment:

```
A <- data.frame(
  "Var1" = c("0", "0", "1", "0"),
  "Var2" = c("1", "0", "0", "0"),
  "Var3" = c("0","1", "1", "1"),
  "Site" = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta" ,"gamma")
)

B <- data.frame(
  "Var4" = c("0", "0", "1", "1"),
  "Var5" = c("1", "0", "0", "1"),
  "Site" = c("alpha", "beta" , "beta" ,"gamma")
)

C <- data.frame(
  "Var6" = c("0", "0", "1"),
  "Var7" = c("1", "0", "0"),
  "Site" = c("alpha", "beta" ,"gamma")
)
```

I would like to create a loop through all the objects in my global environment and subset on the "Site" variable and create and naming the following datasets as:

```
A_alpha = A[A$Site == 'alpha',]
A_beta = A[A$Site == 'beta',]
A_gamma = A[A$Site == 'gamma',]
B_alpha = B[B$Site == 'alpha',]
B_beta = B[B$Site == 'beta',]
B_gamma = B[B$Site == 'gamma',]
C_alpha = C[C$Site == 'alpha',]
C_beta = C[C$Site == 'beta',]
C_gamma = C[C$Site == 'gamma',]
```

How would the loop look like?

Comment: Instead of creating multiple objects, do a `split` into a `list`i..e `split(A, A$Site)`

Comment: Something like `lapply(mget(c("A","B","C")), function(x) split(x, x$Site))` will give you a nice nested list of data.frames which would be much easier to work with in R. Creating a bunch of related but loose variables in the global environment just makes things messier.

Comment: Consider [`eapply`](https://rextester.com/GKFPB70171): `df_list <- Filter(length, eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) split(x, x$Site) else NULL))`